# Why XTK volume object holds nearly 4 times the total memory of DICOM files

Tags: dicom, xtk

I modified [XTK's lesson 13](http://lessons.goxtk.com/13/) to load DICOM images from my desktop and do volume rendering.

Although it is working fine, I noticed that the X.volume object is holding nearly 4 times the total size of pixel data in the DICOM images. Is it an expected behavior, and if not then what is the correct method to do this?

Comment: it may be using `double` as representation for the pixel type instead of the original `short` pixel type (or maybe your DICOM dataset is compressed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that XTK initializes 4 unique volume objects, which leads to this behavior. However it needs only the `X.volume._IJKVolume` object for the final rendering, and rest of the volume objects (i.e. `X.volume.slices`, `X.volume.data` and `X.volume._IJKVolumeN`) are no more needed after `X.volume._IJKVolume` is created.